# How to save data from safari into application document directory

Tags: ios, safari, directory, share, document

I want to implement functionality like the following:

Open a page in safari and choose particular content like image and save, share it in my app document directory.
This is like `pocket app` of android.

Comment: The best way I can think of is to make a JavaScript that the user can inject via a button in their bookmarks bar, which opens your app's custom URL with the content in the URL...

Comment: I could have been able to inject JavaScript if I would use WebView in my app.I am talking about if safari browser here

Comment: Yes, you can copy a JavaScript URL to the clipboard and then the user can create a "bookmark" with it as the URL, so when they open it it will run the code instead of changing the page. See what happens when you copy this into the address bar in Safari: javascript:alert%28%22This%20is%20injected%20code%22%29%3B

Comment: Thanks a lot...do you mean to say if user is on safari he can add particular content to the bookmark and then in my app I can get this bookmarked data by injecting javascript.is it right?